# Whether the connection between php-fpm and nginx by fast-cgi are persistent (keep-alive) connection?

Tags: php, sockets, nginx

I am trying to write a  server demo to connect the php-fpm , but i don't know whether  the    connection between  php-fpm and  nginx      by  fast-cgi are persistent  (keep-alive) connection? 
Every time when  http  request  to  nginx , will the  nginx  connect php-fpm by  tcp 3-Way Handshake  again ?   Or the connection   between nginx and php-fpm  is a  keep-alive  connect  and nginx  try to reuse it ?

Comment: I see a statement, but no question

Comment: @RiggsFolly A bit harsh perhaps? Seems fairly clear to me that question is _Is the connection between php-fpm and nginx by fast-cgi a persistent (keep-alive) connection?_

Comment: Client connects to server, sends request to nginx, nginx may ask PHP-FPM to take care of it (via fcgi), PHP deals with it and produces a response, PHP gives response to nginx, PHP-FPM is done and disconnects from nginx. Whatever happens after that is between nginx and the client.

Comment: @apokryfos  so after the  request ,  the connection  between the  nginx and   php-fpm  will   disconnect?

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur Short answer is yes, long answer is it's complicated. You could realistically create a setup that keeps everything alive from proccess pools to threads pools to connections between FPM and webserver threads. However out of the box this is not what happens.

Comment: No, `php-fpm` and `nginx` **will not** disconnect after request is dispatched. The connection will persist.

Comment: @apokryfos I can't find anything that backs up what you wrote. Do you have any source of proof?

Comment: @Mjh The [fastcgi_keep_conn](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_keep_conn) default is off. Also [keepalive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive) needs `fastcgi_keep_conn` to work. The defaults for this are not to keep connections alive.

Comment: @apokryfos the docs states that `FastCGI` **server** would close the connection. This setting is so `nginx` can tell it it doesn't have to. That doesn't mean `FastCGI` server WILL do so. `php-fpm` isn't the only fcgi server out there. Admittedly, I didn't find whether it would or wouldn't close. You have anything else documented from PHP's side maybe?

Comment: @Mjh The [fastCGI protocol shifts this responsibility to the webserver](http://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html#S3.5) if the webserver does not take on the responsibility to manage the connection then the default behaviour of the protocol is to close the connection at the end of the request. PHP-FPM implements the fastCGI protocol.

Comment: I feel that there's a full answer buried somewhere along all the comments.

Comment: @apokryfos I still can't assert that `php-fpm` WILL disconnect. All the file descriptors I'm monitoring are remaining the same, with their respective identifiers. `php-fpm` docs say nothing about this. It seems super wasteful to reconnect if you don't have to. Thanks for the links though!

Comment: @Mjh the fact that the FPM threads are kept alive does not mean that  the connections with nginx stay alive too. It's not as wasteful as you think. What usually happens is that the OS does not instantly close connections when requested to do so but keeps them suspended if resources permit meaning the reconnect cost is minimal while at the same time the connection is technically terminated. Keep in mind that a socket connection is a finite resource to the OS so minimising the ones that are in use is an optimal strategy.

Comment: I didn't monitor `php-fpm` child processes. I monitored TCP file descriptors. They don't change. They should, if connection is dropped and re-established. Any repeatable work without clear gain is wasteful. I'll fiddle more with this and report back, if it indeed does reconnect on every request - that implies there's room for improving, which would be excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP-FPM is an implementation of the fastCGI protocol, and as such it abides by all the fastCGI specification requirements.

One such requirement is in [section 3.5 of the specification](http://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html#S3.5), specifically about Closing connections:

> The Web server controls the lifetime of transport connections. The Web server can close a connection when no requests are active. Or the Web server can delegate close authority to the application (see FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST). In this case the application closes the connection at the end of a specified request.
>   This flexibility accommodates a variety of application styles. Simple applications will process one request at a time and accept a new transport connection for each request. More complex applications will process concurrent requests, over one or multiple transport connections, and will keep transport connections open for long periods of time.
>
> A simple application gets a significant performance boost by closing the transport connection when it has finished writing its response. The Web server needs to control the connection lifetime for long-lived connections.
>
> When an application closes a connection or finds that a connection has closed, the application initiates a new connection.

This means that it is up to the webserver to decide whether the connection will persist or not. This is implemented in nginx via the [fastcgi_keep_conn](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_keep_conn) option which states:

> By default, a FastCGI server will close a connection right after sending the response. However, when this directive is set to the value on, nginx will instruct a FastCGI server to keep connections open. This is necessary, in particular, for keepalive connections to FastCGI servers to function.

This statement is to reflect the specification behaviour as well as the capability of the webserver that can serve fastCGI generated content to modify the default behaviour.

My assumption here is that there is no real point to keep connections alive since the threads of webservers are constantly recycled. Perhaps there's a specified number of parked threads but the usual policy of thread pooling is to kill the [least recently used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRU) thread, usually this means that spawning a new thread will ensure that pre-exiting threads are the ones that get killed.

Admittedly I have found no resource to back up the claim that the pool collection policy of nginx is LRU but it's not unlikely that it is and in that case keeping the connection alive does not save much.

Answer (score 2):

After a years later i ask this question,i seem to find the answer.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  close () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0x0000000000a40dff in fcgi_close (req=0x1dae3c0, force=0, destroy=1) at /home/dinosaur/Downloads/php-7.2.2/main/fastcgi.c:1311
#2  0x0000000000a41a0d in fcgi_finish_request (req=0x1dae3c0, force_close=0) at /home/dinosaur/Downloads/php-7.2.2/main/fastcgi.c:1670
#3  0x0000000000a4d3b3 in sapi_cgi_deactivate () at /home/dinosaur/Downloads/php-7.2.2/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c:828
#4  0x00000000008bcf35 in sapi_deactivate () at /home/dinosaur/Downloads/php-7.2.2/main/SAPI.c:532
#5  0x00000000008afa0e in php_request_shutdown (dummy=0x0) at /home/dinosaur/Downloads/php-7.2.2/main/main.c:1913
#6  0x0000000000a50614 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffc8b6936e8) at /home/dinosaur/Downloads/php-7.2.2/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c:1994
```

when the php-fpm start ,after init, it while loop to deal with each request

```
while (fcgi_accept_request(request) >= 0) {
   ...
   php_execute_script(&file_handle);   // zend engine compile and run the opcode
   ...
   php_request_shutdown((void *) 0);  // close connection
}
```

in function `fcgi_accept_request`,the socket fd is `4`

```
1411    req->fd = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &len);
(gdb) n
1414    client_sa = sa;
Breakpoint 6, fcgi_accept_request (req=0x1dae3c0) at /home/dinosaur/Downloads/php-7.2.2/main/fastcgi.c:1414
1414    client_sa = sa;
(gdb) p req->fd
$18 = 4
```

when close ,it close the socket fd `4`

```
Breakpoint 4, fcgi_close (req=0x1dae3c0, force=0, destroy=1) at /home/dinosaur/Downloads/php-7.2.2/main/fastcgi.c:1272
1272    {
(gdb) p req->fd
$19 = 4
```

### conclusion

so,i think in php7 ,the fpm is close when the request finish,so it  is not a persistent  connection?